# Problems using 'FDT Font Library' generated .swc in FlashBuilder4

Tags: actionscript-3, air, fdt

I'm working on a AS3/AIR based project, I'm using FDT5 as main tool, but in order to work properly with the other members of my team I need to deploy the AIR in FlashBuilder4.
I used the powerfull FDTFontLibrary tool provided with FDT5 to collect the fonts I need in a swc file. Everything works fine, unless I get back to FlashBuilder where a lot of error like this showup: Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
1044: Interface method addPreloadedRSL in namespace mx.core:IFlexModuleFactory not implemented by class _IndesitMI_mx_managers_SystemManager.   IndesitMI       line 23 Flex Problem

Does anyone have knowledge of limits of tricks that need to be done to have it working properly?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you be a little more specific. How does this relate to the font SWC? Is the font SWC not working? Does it maybe have nothing to do with the font swc and is more about project setup?

Comment: Sure, basically I choose to embed the fonts in a swc via FDTFontLibrary, I add the generated swc to the project resource, which  went fine, and then when I try to add the Font to the project via local var deinition  `private var _appFonts : FontClass_127abec1e7420118;` FlashBuilder starts with the above mentioned error, I believe it's a Flex related issue, due to the project config, but I wasn't able to track more information about it. The swc font works just fine in a AS3/AIR project with FDT, I'm trying to have it work in FlashBuilder Flex project too. I hope it's clearer now. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work in a FDT Flex project?

Comment: Can you please provide an example project please? I can't reproduce. Here are two screenshots:

Comment: FlashBuilder: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/154189/images/stackoverflow/FlashBuilder.png

Comment: FDT: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/154189/images/stackoverflow/FDT.png

Comment: Thanks Alan, in FDT the all thing works perfectly, in FB4 nope.

Comment: It comes to my mind I built the fonts swc using SDK 4.5.1 and the project on FB4 is set to be SDK 4.0 only. Also I wasn't instantiating the font initially, but anyway I can't even compile the project. I made up a sample of the code I'm using.

Comment: FDT font library test, [link] (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7839352/FFLTest.zip)

Comment: It's the end of today for us, we (me & QA) can look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what the issue is; however, it seems it's related to either the AIR runtime you're targeting and/or the SDK you're using. To fix this, make sure you're targeting the latest AIR (3.1+) and Flex SDK (4.6).

I also commented out the instantiation of the Font library.

I loaded your FB 4 project into FB 4.6 and it would not work at all (without the font library). I tried a few different things, such as creating a new description.xml, but it still would not compile. This is likely because of some settings in some of hidden the dot (.) files.

Instead I created a blank project in Flash Builder 4.6 and then loaded the font SWC you created via FDT. The font SWC works fine.

It seems to me that the issue is not the Font SWC or FDT, but rather related to the AIR or Flex SDK you're using, or the instantiation of the font library.

See it working in Flash Builder 4.6 below:

[image: This is the font library working properly in FB 4.6]

Comment: Well, that's fair enough to me, Thanks a lot! For the specific project I can't avoid using FB4.0, so I'll be taking swf font embedding, which works. For the future I'll definetelly keep that in mind! Awesome support!